# How to find the characteristic polynomial of this transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be a finite-dimensional inner product space, and let W ⊂ V be a
subspace. Let T : V → V be the linear transformation “orthogonal projection onto W”:
T(x) = ProjW x.

Show that T is diagonalizable, and find the characteristic polynomial of T.

I know its something to do with starting with a basis for W then extending to a basis for V. Then I project this basis on W to get the matrix. Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Hint for polynomial: a linear operator $P$ is a projector iff $P^2=P$.

As for diagonalisability, consider the basis of $W$ and the basis of $W^\bot$. Can you now build a basis for $V$? How is $T$ written in the obtained basis?